# Vulnerability: Password Exposed

Tags: security, web, passwords, firefox-developer-tools

Today I noticed something strange while building a website. I opened "Dev-Tools" in Firefox and after entering my Email/Password, I actually found them exposed in the "Network" Tab in "Dev-Tools". Is this behavior normal? I found the same thing when I logged in into my Github and Google Account. I am not very experienced in Web Development, but regardless I found this to be strange. I am certain that I am not the first one to notice this, but I just want to know why is this allowed. Thanks in advance for clarifying.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8wOs.png)

Answer (score 2):

What you see in the DevTools is the local, unencrypted data. The encryption of the data happens later in the network request stack.
The same is true for network responses. Their data is decrypted first and then the DevTools display the data.

This is to allow debugging the data on the client side.

So, any data sent over the network is still TLS encrypted when accessing a website which is using HTTP. And there is no security issue in the DevTools displaying passwords or any other raw data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I understand now. I just found it strange that if someone doesn't know much about tech, with a simple trick like this they can get their sensitive info exposed pretty easily.